# How to UNPIVOT a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I'm trying to unpivot my data but getting some weird results. How can I accomplish this?

Below is my code and screenshot of the results. ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/047e18/3))

```
select distinct recId, caseNumber, servtype, mins
from
(
    select 
        recid
        ,caseNumber
        ,[preEnrollment_type]
        ,[preEnrollment_minutes]
        ,[screening_type]
        ,[screeningEnA_minutes]
        ,[ifsp_type]
        ,[ifsp_minutes]
    from
        CaseManagementProgressNote
    where
        [formComplete]=1
        and [reviewed]<>1
        and [dataentry]<>1
        and [caseManagementEntry]=1
        and [serviceCoordinator] <> 'webmaster@company.net'
        and [contactDateTime] >= '1/1/2015'
        and [childID] is not null
) as cp
unpivot
(
    servType for servTypes in ([preEnrollment_type],[screening_type],[ifsp_type])
) as up1
unpivot
(
    mins for minutess in ([preEnrollment_minutes],[screeningEnA_minutes],[ifsp_minutes])
) as up2
order by
    recId
```

Top part is the *strange* `unpivot`ed data and the bottom part is the actual table.

[image]

As you can see in the `unpivot`ed data, the `[column]_type` repeats twice and has incorrect corresponding values.

I need

```
1439 964699 -NA-   null
1439 964699 SC     45
1439 964699 TCM FF 20
```

Take also into account that I still have more columns to select.

This is the reference I was using [mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/047e18/3) of the example above.

Comment: There is a very good chance that you would get a useful answer to your question if you added a SQL Fiddle with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have the impression that your two `UNPIVOT` operations are somehow linked. They're not, other than that the second `UNPIVOT` is performed on the result of the first.

If you look at the results of your first `UNPIVOT`:

```
select *
from
(
    select 
        recid
        ,caseNumber
        ,[preEnrollment_type]
        ,[preEnrollment_minutes]
        ,[screening_type]
        ,[screeningEnA_minutes]
        ,[ifsp_type]
        ,[ifsp_minutes]
    from
        CaseManagementProgressNote
) as cp
unpivot
(
    servType for servTypes in ([preEnrollment_type],[screening_type],[ifsp_type])
) as up1
```

You will see

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╗
║ recid   ║ caseNumber  ║ preEnrollment_minutes  ║ screeningEnA_minutes  ║ ifsp_minutes  ║ servType  ║     servTypes      ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╣
║ 143039  ║     964699  ║ (null)                 ║                   45  ║           20  ║ -NA-      ║ preEnrollment_type ║
║ 143039  ║     964699  ║ (null)                 ║                   45  ║           20  ║ SC        ║ screening_type     ║
║ 143039  ║     964699  ║ (null)                 ║                   45  ║           20  ║ TCM FF    ║ ifsp_type          ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╝
```

It should be clear from this what the second `UNPIVOT` operation does, why it gives you the results it does: to get your desired result from this, you *don't* need to unpivot. `UNPIVOT` transforms columns to rows. That's not what you're looking for. You already have the rows you want. What you want is to put all three `minutes` columns together in one single column, depending on the `servTypes`. There are ways to do that, for instance by adding an expression to your `SELECT` list, like so:

```
CASE servType
WHEN 'preEnrollment_type' THEN preEnrollment_minutes
WHEN 'screening_type' THEN screeningEnA_minutes
WHEN 'ifsp_type' THEN isfp_minutes
END
```

Or use @ander2ed's approach and drop the `UNPIVOT` entirely, if you don't mind that it doesn't filter out the `NULL`s.

The article you link to covers this problem too:

> The only complication here is matching the output phone to the corresponding phone type - for this we need to do some string interrogation to ensure that Phone1 matches to PhoneType1, Phone2 matches to PhoneType2, etc.

It solves it by doing the second `UNPIVOT`, and then filtering the results. You can make it work by linking `servTypes` and `minutess`. In your particular sample data, the first character of them is sufficient for identification, and is the same in the two columns, so you could add `where left(servTypes, 1) = left(minutess, 1)` to your query.

This seems pointlessly complicated to me, and I wouldn't recommend it, but it's the difference between the article and your query, it's the reason your query doesn't work when the article's does.

Comment: I added the `case` statement and it works great!!...and thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cross Apply` in place of `unpivot` here. I find the syntax much easier to understand, and you will be able to retain null values. Try something like:

```
select recid, casenumber, servtype, mins
from CaseManagementProgressNote a
cross apply (VALUES (preEnrollment_type, preEnrollment_minutes),
                    (screening_type, screeningEna_Minutes),
                    (ifsp_type, ifsp_minutes)) unpvt (servtype, mins)
```

Comment: I like the syntax in this query, however it does not run in SQL Server. It does run in SQL Fiddle tho. SQL Server give me the following error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.`

Comment: Interesting. What version of SQL are you using? It works for me in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 r2.

Comment: SQL Server Studio 2012 in my computer, however the actual database is in SQL Server 2005

Comment: I see. I would suspect then that `cross apply (values ())` wasn't supported until SQL Server 2008. That's unfortunate. Glad you found your answer from @hvd though :)